# Python 3 Sha256 of Pillow image and identify -verbose do not equal

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good day!

I can to get sha256 hash for some file using ImageMagick:

```
$ identify -verbose z.png | rg signature
$ signature: 07f130a92bd1e7a2d3d0c6c8e143cddd3a767cdd365cd055317434ff8197c1a8
```

But when I use Pillow on Python 3:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('z.png')

import hashlib
sha=hashlib.sha256(im.tobytes()).hexdigest()
print(sha,'sha256')

>>> 4b705fbc8d6979fdc9a94335a8cf4b870c2424381fd983ec0d520a7383eba994 sha256
```

Program version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-27 Q16-HDRI arm 2022-03-04 https://imagemagick.org
Python 3.9.10
Pillow 9.0.0
```

How can I get equal results?
And why they are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this answer and have no access to a machine to test it for a few days. However, if you look at the version string of your ImageMagick installation, you will see it is Q16 which means ImageMagick holds each sample in a 16-bit unsigned integer, whereas PIL will be using 8-bit integers for each sample.

I think the solution is probably either to map ImageMagick's pixels down to 8-bits, or maybe map PIL's pixels up to 16-bits.

To map ImageMagick's pixels down, I think you would need something like:

```
magick stream -map rgb -storage-type character YOURIMAGE - | sha256sum
```

Or maybe:

```
magick YOURIMAGE -depth 8 rgb:- | sha256sum
```

---

Going the other way, and scaling PIL's 8-bit unsigned up to 16-bit, I imagine you'd want something like:

```
Im = Image.open(YOURIMAGE).convert('RGB')
Na = np.array(im).astype(np.uint16))
```

Then you can use:

```
sha=hashlib.sha256(Na.tobytes()).hexdigest()
```

---

Thinking about this a little further, you may have fundamental issues if your PNG images are 16-bit RGB(A) because PIL probably won't load them at all.

Also, I am not sure what happens if your images are palette/indexed images - I don't know if ImageMagick checksums just the indices, or whether it looks up the indices in the palette to make an RGB image and then checksums the result.

Comment: construct : 
`import numpy as np
arr=np.array(im).astype(np.uint16)
sha=hashlib.sha256(arr.tobytes()).hexdigest()
print(sha,'sha256 <-- np.uint16')` 
return `0660af1aa16aa89b4c292d2cea166fe2e792d9c0a04ca799f371c4cf40a41db9 sha256 <-- np.uint16`. But `$ magick z.png -depth 8 rgb:- | shasum -a 256` return `$ 4b705fbc8d6979fdc9a94335a8cf4b870c2424381fd983ec0d520a7383eba994`, like `sha=hashlib.sha256(im.tobytes()).hexdigest()`

Comment: In your Python code in your question please add `print(im)` so we can see its type/mode.